# Boost result which has the current date in between dates

Tags: elasticsearch

My mapping has two properties:

```json
"news_from_date" : {
    "type" : "string"
},
"news_to_date" : {
    "type" : "string"
},
```

Search results have the properties news_from_date, news_to_date

```
curl -X GET 'http://172.2.0.5:9200/test_idx1/_search?pretty=true' 2>&1
```

Result:

```json
{
    "news_from_date" : "2022-05-30 00:00:00",
    "news_to_date" : "2022-06-23 00:00:00"
}
```

Question is: How can I boost all results with the current date being in between their "news_from_date"-"news_to_date" interval, so they are shown as highest ranking results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

First off if you are going to play with dates, you should probably use the one of the dates type provided by `Elasticsearch`.

They are many way to approach you problem, using painless, using scoring function or even more classical query types.

## Using `Should`

Using the [Boolean query type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#query-dsl-bool-query), you have multiple clauses.

- Must
- Filter
- Must_not
- Should

`Should` allow [for optionals clause](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#bool-min-should-match) to be factored in the final score.

So you go with:

```json
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "news_from_date": {
              "gte": "now"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "news_to_date": {
              "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Be aware that:

> You can use the minimum_should_match parameter to specify the number or percentage of should clauses returned documents must match.
>
> If the bool query includes at least one should clause and no must or filter clauses, the default value is 1. Otherwise, the default value is 0.

## Using a script

As provided by [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-script-score), you can create a custom function to score your documents according to your own business rules.

The script is using [Painless](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-painless.html) (a stripped down version of java)

```json
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": { "message": "elasticsearch" }
      },
      "script_score": {
        "script": {
          "source": "Math.log(2 + doc['my-int'].value)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```